# Using foreach loop to find GameObjects that are children of something else (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, foreach, gameobject

I am making a video game, and while I have an existing code in generic C#, I now have to move it to Unity. I have some basic knowledge with generic C#, but I just started to learn the Unity way of coding.

For starters, I want to write a code that positions all game areas to correct positions, then turn them invisible. Yes, don't be surprised, they need to be all in same places.

Areas can have three size options, I called them Small, Medium and Large. Small and large areas have to be written manually.

```
 List <GameObject> SmallAreas = new List<GameObject>();

void DefineSmallAreas()
{
    SmallAreas.Add(areaConfirmLoad);
    SmallAreas.Add(areaConfirmQuit);
    SmallAreas.Add(areaConfirmSave);
    SmallAreas.Add(areaGameSaved);
    SmallAreas.Add(areaSave);
    SmallAreas.Add(areaLoad);   
}
```

Same with large areas.

Now, all other areas, are medium, and there is a large number of them.

**So, I want to go through all game objects that are children of "areaContainer", check if their names start with "area", and if they do, I want to add them to MediumAreas list.**

That's how I tried it:

```
void DefineMediumAreas()
{
    GameObject areaContainer = GameObject.Find("areaContainer");

    foreach (GameObject thisObject in areaContainer)
    {
        char[] a = thisObject.Name.ToCharArray();
        if (a.Length >= 4)
        {
        char[] b = { a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3] };
        string thisObjectType = new string(b);
                        (if (thisObjectType == "area")&&(!(SmallAreas.Contains(thisObject))
                        &&(!(LargeAreas.Contains(thisObject)))
                        {
                            MediumAreas.Add(thisObject);
                        }
    }   
}
```

This however shows an error, that "areaContainer" can't be used that way, I don't have access to Unity now, so can't copy exact message. I think that it's something like "Gameobject doesn't have IEnumerator".

I did try to google for the better approach, and found something called "transform".

```
 foreach(Transform child in transform)
 {
     Something(child.gameObject);
 }
```

**What I don't understand, is how to use this "transform" in my specific situation.**

Please don't get angry at me if this question is silly, I am very new to Unity, and have to learn it from scratch.

And a small second question. Will this work of turning object invisible work:

```
    foreach(GameObject thisObject in MediumAreas)
    {
        thisObject.position = MediumVector;
        thisObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
    }
```

MediumVector is location where the object must be moved to, and it seems to be working.

Comment: A side note: you can use thisObject.Name.StartsWith("area") to check if the name starts with "area".

Comment: Another side note: if you're planning to do anything non-trivial with Unity3D, you absolutely need to learn what is transform and how to use it. This is one of the key concepts of the engine.

Comment: This is not how you use `foreach`. Do `areaContainer` have a property which is a collection of `GameObjects`? If so, then use `foreach(GameObject thisObject in areaContainer.collectionsOfObjects){...}` (this is at least how you do it in C#)

Comment: areaContainer is object that includes all other objects. Also, thank you for saying about "Name.StartsWith"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can** do this: `foreach(Transform child in transform)`

because the `Transform` class implements `IEnumerable` and have some mechanism that enables you to access the child GameObjects with the `foreach` loop.

---

Unfortunately, you **can't** do this: `foreach (GameObject thisObject in areaContainer)`

because `areaContainer` is a `GameObject` and this implementation is not done for the `GameObject` class. That's why you are getting this error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'UnityEngine.GameObject' because 'UnityEngine.GameObject' does not
>   contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

To fix it, change your loop to use `Transform` after finding the `GameObject`:

```
GameObject areaContainer = GameObject.Find("areaContainer");
foreach (Transform thisObject in areaContainer.transform){}
```

The complete code:

```
List<GameObject> MediumAreas = new List<GameObject>();

void DefineMediumAreas()
{
    GameObject areaContainer = GameObject.Find("areaContainer");
    foreach (Transform thisObject in areaContainer.transform)
    {
        //Check if it contains area
        if (thisObject.name.StartsWith("area"))
        {
            //Add to MediumAreas List
            MediumAreas.Add(thisObject.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Everybody else seems glance over the actual issue which is `foreach (GameObject thisObject in areaContainer)`. I did a test with `foreach (Transform thisObject in areaContainer.transform){}` and it works so that's the issue. Using the `transform` property fixed the issue.

Comment: @PassetCronUs That's right. Other ways people mentioned should work too. I just like pointing out why code is not working and adding the closet similar solution with minimal code changes.

Comment: @Programmer Can you also reply about how to turn object invisible? Or the code I am using should work?

Comment: It depends on the type of object. What type of object is that? A screenshot of the "Inspector" tab would be helpful since it will have components that describe the type

Comment: @Programmer I am at work, can't show screenshot now. But mostly I am talking about usual 2d images.

Comment: There is a SpriteRender, UI components such as Image and RawImage. If SpriteRender then your code is fine

Comment: Again, thank you, I'll try. If everything works, I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: @Programmer, sorry for bothering again, now I remember I made them as UI Images. Will the code work?

Comment: UPD: Best to turn invisible the whole "area" game element, with all images inside it. Usually "area" is game object with main image, and all other buttons and images are it's children.

Comment: In that case, disable the UI component. Lets say that it' an image component, do this: `thisObject.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;`. If you have many child objects in the object you want to hide, deactivate the GameObject. `thisObject.SetActive(false);`

Comment: Your answer worked, same with last comment. I marked it as best answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple approaches to your problem. One of them is using **Tags**. Simply mark your *MediumArea prefab* with some Tag and then you can find all tagged GameObjects with  `FindGameObjectsWithTag(string)` ([Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html)). Then you can populate your collection like that:

```
MediumAreas.AddRange(FindGameObjectsWithTag("MediumArea"));
```

Second approach could be finding all objects with same attached script `FindObjectsOfType<T>()` ([Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html)). This is usefull when you are searching for instances of same type, like *Medium Area*.

Lets say that you have an **Area** script

```
public class Area : MonoBehaviour {
    public AreaSize Size;    // AreaSize is Enum
}
```

Then you can simply find your areas like:

```
var allAreas = FindGameObjectsOfType<Area>();
var mediumAreas = allAreas.Where(e => e.Size == AreaSize.Medium); // using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a look. I guess same can be done with all other objects too?

Answer (score 0):

You want to access all game objects that are children of "areaContainer"

In `void DefineMediumAreas()` function, you need to `Transform[]` to get an array of childeren. Use this:

```
Transform[] areaContainer = GameObject.Find("areaContainer").GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

foreach(Transform thisTransform in areaContainer)
{
  ...
}
```

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I created a project to answer your question, the final result will be like this :

[image]

As you can see I have created a game object called "areaContainer" and added 3 children with respective names : "area01", "area02" and  "anotherObject".

The script that manage to get all "areaContainer" children that start with "area" looks like :

```
public GameObject areaContainer;
public List<GameObject> MediumAreas = new List<GameObject>();

private void Start()
{
    DefineMediumAreas();
}

void DefineMediumAreas()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < areaContainer.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        var childGameObject = areaContainer.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
        if (childGameObject.name.StartsWith("area"))
            MediumAreas.Add(childGameObject);
    }
}
```

1- I ended up referencing the areaContainer object in a script rather than using GameObject.Find because it's more performant.

2- To get a child of a game object you need to access to its transform and call GetChild(index). So by iterating through the parent container which is "areaContainer" we are getting its childCount.

3- To check if the name start with "area", simply use .StartsWith("area") which return true or false.

---

For your second question, you can hide object disabling the Renderer or by deactivating it (thisObject.SetActive(false);

I hope this help you; Happy coding!